# Do you know of a browser that won't hog bandwidth?

Tags: mac, browser, skype

Every time I use a browser when I'm on Skype, my Skype connection loses power and it's hard to hear the person on the other end of the call.

Do you know of a Mac browser that won't hog up bandwidth and therefore leave enough for my conversation?

Comment: Just to highlight what all of the answers (thus far) are basically saying: it's not the browser that's hogging the bandwidth, it's what you're viewing with it that's doing it. Switching to a browser that doesn't download and display bandwidth heavy elements (such as images) is one to solve the issue.

Answer (score 3):

Opera has a feature called "Turbo" that might reduce your bandwidth usage: http://www.opera.com/browser/turbo/

...and yes, it's available for OS X: http://www.opera.com/download/?platform=mac

It's also possible that your browser is using up much of your system's available RAM and that is causing degradation of Skype's performance. Have you tried closing some tabs (assuming you have many tabs open)?

Answer (score 3):

you could try using lynx it would most likely have the least overhead. but it is also a terminal web browser.

http://lynx.browser.org/

its cool to play with and can get your info while on your call.

Answer (score 0):

AdBlock and any of the script blocking plugins in Firefox can shrink the amount of info downloaded by sites to the bare minimum necessary.

But, echoing others here: your problem is not the browser, it's the sites you're viewing.

Watching Youtube or Netflix, or even just loading Facebook or any current webmail client will take quite a bit of bandwidth and will therefore cause your Skype connection to be interrupted. Changing your browser will not change this.